# Rails server as database for mobile app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cordova

I would like to test some mobile app development.

I choose to use Rails as my back-end and Phonegap as my front-end.
What do you think about those choice ?

I already manage to register a user from my app (Using AVD) to my server Rails.

But now, after registering the user, rails want to redirect to a page on the rails server. But I don't want it, is it possible that Rails send a "callback" (or whatever) to my mobile app that say "Ok the user is register" and then perform an action in my mobile app according to this message ?

My register form looks like

> form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="http://3dcb84c4.ngrok.com/users" id="new_user" method="post">
>
> ```
>   <label for="user_name">Pseudo</label>
>   <input id="user_name" name="user[name]" type="text">
>
>   <br>
>
>   <label for="user_email">Email</label>
>   <input id="user_email" name="user[email]" type="email">
>
>
>     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
> </form>
> ```

And my controller on my server looks like

> def create
>       @user = User.new(user_params)
>
> ```
> if @user.save
>   # send OK
> else
>   # something
> end   end
> ```

thanks

Comment: You are probably looking on how to build an API, I'm putting a tutorial on this, you can check it out on http://apionrails.icalialabs.com/book/

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the [rails-api gem](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api).

Answer (score 0):

you have to respond to the format and if it is js you have to

```
 msg = {:status => 200, msg_text => 'Ok the user is register'}
 render json: msg
```

instead of render the default erb.